# Current travel restrictions from Germany to France (and return) via Amsterdam on KLM

Tags: air-travel, germany, france, covid-19, netherlands

I would like to understand the regulations and restrictions for an Indian national with German temporary residence (expiring at the end of this year), who has been fully vaccinated in Germany more than 14 days ago, and has a EU Digital Covid Vaccination Certificate. The intended journey dates are later this month. I am listing my current understanding below, and would appreciate feedback in case I have missed something:

1. Germany - Netherlands (transit): Germany is designated as a safe country by [the Netherlands](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/checklist-entry/from-the-eu), and no proof of vaccination, recovery or negative test is required.
2. Netherlands - France: Germany and Netherlands are both designated as "green list" by [France](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/), proof of vaccination and a sworn declaration are required - since this is a requirement of the destination, it would be required to board the flight in Germany. Quarantine or tests not required.
3. France - Netherlands (transit): [The Netherlands](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/checklist-entry/from-the-eu) designates France as a "high risk area". This journey is allowed but only proof of vaccination is required, no tests.
4. Netherlands - Germany: The part of France where this journey originates is classified [by Germany](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Transport/Archiv_Risikogebiete/Risikogebiete_2021-08-20_en.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) as a "high risk area", and as per information [here](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-einreisende-englisch.html), the traveller must complete the Digital Entry Registration and submit proof of vaccination, but no testing or quarantine is necessary. As before, Entry Registration must be completed before boarding the flight in France.

Have I missed anything?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.